# Exception NOSUCHMETHODERROR when calling Java method from C through JNI

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I have a problem sharing a stream between Java and C with JNI. I am trying to call a Java method from C, but I am getting a `nosuchmethodfound` exception when I am trying to get `GetObjectMethodID`.

C Code:

```
jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, obj);
jmethodID aMethodID = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, cls, "callbackmethod", "(I)V");
if (aMethodID == 0) { 
    log("Unable to get methodID"); //Always getting aMethodID as 0
}
int myvar = 7;
(*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, obj, aMethodID, myvar);
```

Java Code:

```
public class myclass extends activity {
    private void callbackmethod(int i) {
        Log.d("Tag", "In Java code");
    }

    -------
    more code
}
```

Now I am always getting an error `Ljava/lang/NoSuchMethodError;: callbackmethod`.

Everything looks fine, but my code doesn't work. What is the problem?

Comment: Do I need to Include any header file? That is only thing That i can think of right now

Comment: Update your C, Java source to reflect actual snippets, then resolution would be faster. Did you generate the signature for callabckmethod() correctly?

Comment: MAy be that is the case. How should I generate the signatures?

Comment: I have verified that the generated signatures are correct. The problem is something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was my mistake. I was calling the native function from the java static function. I removed the static key word. It's working fine now.

Comment: why the down votes ? They owned up to the mistake, everyone can make a   mistake after all

Comment: Thanks, I had a similar issue and this pointed me to the right fix

Answer (score 5):

Is the JNI method static by any chance? If so, its second parameter is the class, not the `this` pointer of the current object.

Also, is the method in question in the current class or in its base? Judging by the fact that you spelled `activity` in all lower case, this is not a copy/paste of your actual code, but a rewrite. It's easier to find errors in real code.